# Play Framework 1.2.4: Close or Disconnect the session after bulk insert job?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, playframework, bulkinsert

i am working on a play 1.2.4 project and i have 4 jobs running in intervals, fetching bulk data (from webservice) and saves them to the database.

My current bulk insert method is like this:

```
      org.hibernate.Session session = 
            (org.hibernate.Session)MyEntityModel.em().getDelegate(); 
  Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
  int i = 0;
  for(Sales obj:sales)
      {
            convertToModelAndSave(obj);
          i++;
          if(i%100==0)
          {
              tx.commit();
              session.flush();
              session.clear();
              tx=session.beginTransaction();
          }
      }
  session.disconnect();
```

i am simply disconnecting the session after job is done.

I am wondering if this is enough for me, do i really need to disconnect the session (which gives me exceptions in the program). Will my database connection pool be release after disconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to split your work in two jobs.

- The first job is the main one, it splits your data into chunks of 100 items
- The second one take some items and save them

Then your first job call the second one and you don't have to put hibernate related code in your code.

Another advantage : if you have a rollback while saving 100 items, your main job can then retry by saving items one by one in this case to avoid loosing 100 items for one error

You can also in this case launch several subjobs in parallel to go faster

Comment: That sounds like a nice idea!, i will try and see the performance results. That was the main reason why i got through all those things.

Comment: Thanks, that actually saved me a lot of error handling unlike the other method, also i havent seen any impact on performance.

Comment: i have created a master which splits data into chunks and send them to worker jobs. i execute the jobs with worker.now() so the are parallel also.